# Encode several values in a categorical column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, character-encoding

I have a dataframe column with over 150 uniqe color values. The color values contain both RAL, NCS and other color strings. I want to encode them based on if they are categorized as RAL, NCS or other. I also want to separate the dark and light NCS colors. With built in encoder functions I get a unique column for each color, but I want to map the different colors before I encode them.

In summary, I want to encode the column into 4 values:

0 - light NCS
1 - dark NCS
2 - RAL
3 - other

Example of the objects in the column:

```
['NCS S 8500 N ', 'NCS S 9000 N ', 'NCS S 0502 Y', 'RAL 9004 ', 'NCS S 7500 N', 'NCS S 8000 N', 'NCS S 0500 N ', 'RAL 9005 ', 'RAL 9011 ', 'NCS S 5502 Y', 'RAL 8022 ', 'RAL 7016', 'NCS S 6502 G', 'Klar lakk']
```

I have tried to map the column based on the substrings "RAL" and "NCS" and assign them a value. The error is raised when I try to do it multiple times. the dataframe is 'df_test' and the column containing the color codes are 'maling_utv'.

I have tried to replace the values based on the substring with loc():

```
df_test.loc[df_test['maling_utv'].str.contains('RAL', case=False), 'maling_utv'] = 2
df_test.loc[df_test['maling_utv'].str.contains('NCS', case=False), 'maling_utv'] = 1
```

this only works for the first condition and raise the error " Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values".

I have also tried with np.where() function, but the same problem occurs for the second case.

```
df_test['maling_utv'] = np.where(df_test['maling_utv'].str.contains('NCS'), 2)
df_test['maling_utv'] = np.where(df_test['maling_utv'].str.contains('RAL'), 2)
```

where the error "either both or neither of x and y should be given" is raised.

Additionally, I have tried to mask the column:

```
df_test['maling_utv'] = df_test['maling_utv'].mask(df_test['maling_utv'].str.contains("NCS"), 1)
df_test['maling_utv'] = df_test['maling_utv'].mask(df_test['maling_utv'].str.contains("RAL"), 2)
```

this raises the error "bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'".

Comment: Your input dataset is unclear, can you provide a minimal `pd.DataFrame(...)` constructor and the matching expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.extract` and create a mapping dict to set numeric values:

```
dmap = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(['light', 'NCS', 'RAL'])}
pattern = f"({'|'.join(dmap.keys())})"

df['code'] = (df['maling_utv'].str.extract(pattern, expand=False)
                              .map(dmap).fillna(3).astype(int))
print(df)

# Output
      maling_utv  code
0   NCS S 8500 N     1
1   NCS S 9000 N     1
2   NCS S 0502 Y     1
3       RAL 9004     2
4   NCS S 7500 N     1
5   NCS S 8000 N     1
6   NCS S 0500 N     1
7       RAL 9005     2
8       RAL 9011     2
9   NCS S 5502 Y     1
10      RAL 8022     2
11      RAL 7016     2
12  NCS S 6502 G     1
13     Klar lakk     3
```

Details:

```
>>> dmap
{'light': 0, 'NCS': 1, 'RAL': 2}

>>> pattern
'(light|NCS|RAL)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You werent using `np.where` correctly. The function needs an else condition as well.
The else condition can include another `np.where` as well.

You could use something like this as well:

```
df['code'] = np.where(df['mailing_utv'].str.contains('light'), 0,
                              np.where(df['mailing_utv'].str.contains('NCS'), 1,
                                       np.where(df['mailing_utv'].str.contains('RAL'), 2, 3)))
```

Comment: Using multiple nested `np.where` is equivalent to use `np.select`